# angularjs + foundation orbit

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

Hi I want to fill content for Foundation orbit slider dynamically using angular like:

```
<div class="moreGamesArea">
    <ul class="orbit" data-orbit>
        <li ng-repeat="games in catalogGames">
            <div>{{games[0]}}</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But it doesn't initialize slider correctly. In dom-model I see 3 elements `<li>` as it should be - so angular works ok, but slider - has only one slide! whats wrong? Thanks

Comment: Can you post links to the slider? Also, can you fix the spelling mistakes in your post at the same time (sHi, wring)

Comment: Fixed mistakes) But I can't put link to the slider, because it's a local page that is part of JSP page, so I can't put it outside of my project =(

Comment: @Simha how did you fix it, i am in the same situation but couldn't fix it so far

Comment: @shadesco hi, sorry, but it was a long time ago, so I don't remember.

Comment: @Simha it's ok i fixed it. Waited for ng-repeat to finish then loaded foundation(orbit). If (scope.$last ==="true") { load orbit here }

Answer (score 3):

First. You need to create a directive.

```
.directive('afterRenderRepeat', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (scope.$last){
        $(document).foundation();
    }
 };
})
```

Second. Call it in section ng-repeat.

```
<div class="moreGamesArea">
    <ul class="orbit" data-orbit>
        <li ng-repeat="games in catalogGames" data-after-render-repeat>
            <div>{{games[0]}}</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The Directive has helped me to release foundation 5.

Answer (score 0):

in Foundation 6 to initialize orbit use:

Foundation.reInit('orbit');

---

```
.directive('initOrbit', function(){
    return function(scope) {
        if (scope.$last){             //  when  ng-repeat finish to load all elements
            Foundation.reInit('orbit');   // reinit orbit
        }
    };
})
```

---

```
<ul class="orbit-container">
    <li class="orbit-slide" ng-repeat="slide in slides" init-orbit>
```

---

more: https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html#initializing